# How to partially rollback data in spring boot, errors to be persited

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have sequence of table data creation in transaction, using `springboot`, `java`, `jpa` and `hibernate` sequence shown below. Database used is `Oracle`

1. Place order - insert into order details_table
2. Process Payment - insert into payment_info table
3. Error Message(info, warning, error) - insert into error_message table

I am inserting error messages in `error_message` table if any error occurs(info, warning, error).
My info and warning message get persisted into `error_message` if no error occurs during the processing of the request.
But if there is an error, I am throwing an error from code to rollback the `transaction`, its working but my `error_message` also get rollback.

I want to rollback `details_table` and `payment_info` but not the `error_message`, I want them to be persisted.

How I can achieve the same?

Comment: Use PL/SQL procedure with [pragma autonomous_transaction](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/autotransaction_pragma.htm) to save data into error_message table

Comment: use  `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) ` on save error_message method ,https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation-requires_new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two different transactions.

The default transaction propagation is `REQUIRED`, when calling your `@Transactional` annotated method without a transactional context, a new transaction will be started but if there's already a transaction in place, the transaction will be joined, ending up with a single transaction. In case of rollback, all operations will be rollbacked as they belong to the same transaction.

Change the transaction propagation to `REQUIRES_NEW` in order to always force starting a new transaction (instead of joining it if there's one). This will allow you to commit the error messages transaction independently from the payment info.

```java
@Transactional
public void placeOrder(Order oder) {
  // process order
  
  paymentGateway.processPayment();

  // save order <- an exception here will rollback the current 
  // transaction but not the one in PaymentGateway which is independent
} 

// In PaymentGateway
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void processPayment() {
  // process payment
  // insert error messages
}
```

Further reading: [Understanding PROPAGATION_REQUIRED](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#tx-propagation-required). Make sure you also understand how exceptions affect transactions.

Comment: In the above case, my order data is also getting rolled back if there is no error

Comment: By default, the transaction will commit, make sure you understand how exceptions trigger rollback