# Spring Autonomous Transaction - Execute secondary then throw primary

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I am having trouble with Spring Transactions. I need my **catch block to persist some state** on a **forked/autonomous transaction** then throw an exception to rollback whatever there was done on the primary transaction.

```
  @Transactional(
      propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED,
      isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED,
      rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
  public void createApplication() {
    try {
      saveState(0);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      saveState(1);

      throw e;
    }
  }

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void saveState(Integet stateId) {
    ...
  }
```

The issue with this setup is that everything gets rollbacked (as mentioned in [How to partially rollback data in spring boot, errors to be persited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64273779/how-to-partially-rollback-data-in-spring-boot-errors-to-be-persited)). Is there a way to fork transactions in Spring or this way is fundamentally incorrect?

I've also tried pairing **Propagation.REQUIRED** with **Propagation.NESTED** without avail.

Comment: This won't work, as it is an internal method call.

Comment: Currently, `@Transactional` on `saveState` is ignored. To make your `saveState` transaction work, you need to use AspectJ or inject your service in itself. More info in answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423972/spring-transaction-method-call-by-the-method-within-the-same-class-does-not-wo

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because you are having your second `@Transactional` method in the same class. **Remember that `@Transactional` only works if the call goes through the proxy.** Just move this `saveState` to another class and I am sure it is going to work because the rest of your code is perfectly correct.